# Google API causes huge page hangs in Electron

Tags: youtube-api, freeze, electron

I'm building a desktop app in Electron, and I'm having a problem with the Google API. You can view my source code [here](http://github.com/rittbys/YouTubeDesktop).

Essentially, the problem is that it is trying to load four images (file://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/bubblev1/bubbleDropB_3.png) and the like, but they obviously do not exist. My theory on why this is happening is that it is using relative urls that assume the page is loaded at Http://..., which it is not. How can I resolve this? It's not really something that I can just ignore because the page is unresponsive for a good 15 seconds when it loads. Thanks!

Comment: That's an interesting case, is that happening on page loading ?

Comment: It's happening when the page loads, yes. It happens whenever I reload the page as well.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me when when requesting using ytdl-core the page freezes for like 2 secs